# Проблемы с кодировкой. Idea добавляет BOM в начале файла

Tags: java, intellij-idea, thymeleaf, bom

Изменил html файл, сохранил, и тут сервер начал ругаться (использую Thymeleaf и Spring):

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 19; 
An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.
```

Спасибо, что был некий опыт на PHP, где были подобные проблемы и я сразу подумал на BOM и убрал его Notepado'м. Почему Idea вообще это делает? Раньше при сохранении такого не было, теперь есть (ничего не менял в настройках), то есть с того ни сего эта проблема появилась. Как это убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался. Во первых Thymeleaf (хотя может и не в нем дело) достаточно придирчив к кодировкам. Во вторых Idea как только увидит в html файле charset сразу же пытается сохранить файл в этом формате. Вот только работает это в сторону увеличения. Если был UTF-8 и мы записали UTF-16, среда поможет нам, пересохранив файл в формате UTF-16. Но вот если мы вернем UTF-8, то файл уже не преобразуется. Наверное по логике что в UTF-16 влезет UTF-8, а в UTF-8 не влезет UTF-16. Своеобразно конечно.

У кого будут такие же проблемы с кодировкой. Следите, чтобы всё было в одном формате. Если у вас HTML в формате UTF-8 и вы используете локализацию из файла properties, то у этого файла тоже должна быть кодировка UTF-8! (По умолчанию windows-1251, а у остальных файлов по умолчанию UTF-8). Заходим в меню File encoding через Settings и там всё прописываем.

В общем в который раз замечаю, что вся эта "автоматика" только мешает. Позволяет наткнуться на грабли и поиграться с ошибками из воздуха.